# C++ Code to calculate sum of unknown number of numbers

Tags: c++, while-loop

Im trying to write a code in c++ that takes an unknown number of numbers and adds them all together. I do not get any errors but when i input numbers it wont do anything.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int sum = 0, val;
   while (std::cin >> val)
       sum += val;
   std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the terminal i type:                                                   1 2 3 4 Enter and then it just goes to a new line in the terminal instead of displaying Sum is: 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you never ended your input. It will continue looping and adding numbers until you trigger end of file. Just pressing enter won't do that - you need to hit `ctrl+d` on Linux or `ctrl+z` on Windows to end  the standard input file, allowing the while loop to exit.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked it said that in the book but for some reason i didnt really understand when to press that and why i need to press it but that works

Comment: Yeah, it just signals that you're done. Then the "file" is closed and cin knows it is at the end and breaks the loop.